# my site showing up in chrome and firefox but not in safari and edge

Tags: wordpress, safari, internet-explorer-11

My current project is showing up nicely in chrome and firefox browsers but does not showing up in safari and internet explorer browsers. Here is the link for my site, [http://www.grahamkellyphotography.com/landscape-photography-ireland/blog/](http://www.grahamkellyphotography.com/landscape-photography-ireland/blog)

The issue is totally killing me as same site is working fine on other browsers but not working in safari and internet browsers.

Comment: I cant use inspect element in your site (right click disable). please remove right click. so i can use inspect element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a .js issue or conflict.

Which theme are you using? Is the theme working in safari and IE in the original theme demo?

Comment: my own custom theme I am using

Comment: yes it worked it was conflict of jquery ... thanks for pointing me head towards that ...